# extract characters from documents in sharepoint library

Tags: metadata, formula

I have a sharepoint online library where I have some files which are names liked: AG_11-08-2021 or CE_11-08-2021 etc or FLASH_08-11-2022. It is always the same type of name, the first letters are here to define the type of event.

I just wonder, how can I "extract" the content of only the text to a calculated formula ?

I have my title column which indicates the name (like CE_11-08-2021) and I would like the calculated formula to show CE in this case.

I tried using a formula like: =LEFT([Title]",INT(FIND("_",[Title])-1)) but it says error all the time, whereas I though it would be working.

Is there anyone who have an idea ?

Thanks in advance for your previous help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below formula in SharePoint library

```
=IFERROR((LEFT([Title],(FIND("_",[Title])-1))),[Title])
```

Refer the below screen shot of SharePoint list.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply. It is amazing to see it working on your side. But, it is maybe a mistery, everytime I create a new column with calculated value, I copy paste your function and when I want to save, it says "syntax error or not supported". We have a O365 licence with sharepoint online, same as you from what I can see on your screenshot. Do you have any idea what may be the issue ?

Thanks again for your assistance.

Comment: Ahh ! I know what the issue is. I am based in Canada and using French as a language. And in France (or French speaking countries), we do not have to use "," but ";" instead. I changed it and it works perfectly ! Sorry for that and thanks again for your precious Help Rajat !

Comment: Please accept as answer and upvote it as it is working. this is how we help each other.